# Why ping attribute not working correctly in html5

Tags: php, html, localhost, ping

Hi I'm building a tracking system for my project and I'm trying to use the `ping` attribute, but this attribute not working correctly on `localhost`.

Here is my code with PHP

```
echo "<a href='".$r_url."' ping='/redirect?url=".$r_url."'>";
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working correctly on localhost" ? What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior? Does it work on your server?

Comment: It'd also be important to know the target browsers. In Firefox, for instance, the user needs to knowingly enable the feature.

Comment: @NoahBoegli, I also test this on server and the problem is this it only redirecting to href url not  redirecting through ping url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your post and the information you gave in the comments, you are trying to redirect through the link in the `ping` attribute.

In the [W3C documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_ping.asp):

> The ping attribute specifies a list of URLs to be notified if the user follows the hyperlink.

Which means that the user is not directly redirected to this URL, instead this happens:

1. User clicks on the link
2. The browser sends a `POST` request to the URL in the `ping` attribute
3. The browser redirects the user to the URL in the `href` attribute

If you want to redirect through a URL, simply put your redirection URL in the `href` attribute:

```php
echo "<a href='/redirect?url=".$r_url."'>";
```

Comment: Thank you friend I'm already using this way, but I'm confused from this method thank you for your quick explanation

Comment: regarding your step 2: according to current MDN, it's a POST request that's being sent - see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: @okram Thanks for the correction, I can't remember if it used to be a GET request or if I simply misread it. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score -3):

I hope is not too late for you to get this answer:

You should use $_SERVER instead of $_POST

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it